# Save & Retrieve TableViewCell checkmark using NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to save and retrieve tableViewCell checkmark using NSUserDefaults.My partial code as below.From the code,I can able to select or deselect cell using UITableViewCellAccessoryType.I am not familiar using NSUserDefaults in Swift.Please,someone point me the direction...

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    cell.textLabel!.text = myItems[indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    return cell
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A solution depends on whether the number of items in the table view and the order can change over a relaunch of the app.

Comment: @vadian .I have a largely populated tableview. so i preferred the selected cell to be saved and moved to the top.Thanks

Comment: You should give as much information as possible. Your code suggests (`...multipleSelection = true`) that you can select multiple cells and you want to save them all.

Comment: @vadian. I want to save all selected cell.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all create a class `Item` as data source with a `name` and `selected` property.

  ```
  class Item {
    let name : String
    var selected = false

    init(name: String) {
      self.name = name
    }
  }
  ```
- Declare the data source array

  ```
  var myItems = [Item]()
  ```
- Create the items this way

  ```
  let item = Item(name:"Foo") // your former string value, `selected` is false by default.
  myItems.append(item)
  ```
- In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` register an empty string array as default value for key `selectedCells`

  ```
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  let defaultValues = ["selectedCells" : [String]()]
  defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
  ```
- To read all selected cells from user defaults get the string array and set the property `selected` of all corresponding items to true. Then reload the table view. The forced unwrapping is safe because the key/value is pre-registered and always non-optional. **Important:** Make sure that `readDefaults()` is always called **after** registering the default values.

  ```
  func readDefaults()
  {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let selectedItems = defaults.stringArrayForKey("selectedCells")!
    for item in myItems {
      item.selected = selectedItems.contains(item.name)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```
- In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set both properties accordingly

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let item = myItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = item.name
    cell.accessoryType = item.selected ? .Checkmark : .None
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    return cell
  }
  ```
- To save the data filter all items whose `selected` property is true, map it to the names and save the array.

  ```
  func saveDefaults() {
    let selectedCells = myItems.filter { $0.selected }.map { $0.name }
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(selectedCells, forKey:"selectedCells")
  }
  ```
- Now you should change the model in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and reload the row. This is much more efficient (and recommended) than manipulating the cell

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let item = myItems[indexPath.row]
    item.selected = true
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

My example, i Load in tableView set in DetailController

Model ----

```
struct TheoryData {

    var id: String
    var theoryText: String
    var theoryModes: String
    var theoryImage: String
    var like: Bool
}
```

Read values

```
   var theoryData = [TheoryData]()

private func readDefaults() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let selectedItems = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "selectedCells") ?? []
    
    (0..<theoryData.count).forEach { i in
        theoryData[i].like = selectedItems.contains(theoryData[i].id)
    }
    menuTableView.reloadData()
}

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    readDefaults()
}
```

In cell

```
let theory = theoryData[indexPath.row]
cell.likeImage.image = theory.like ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart-icon") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart-empty-icon")
```

Save state in UserDefault

```
    @IBAction func likeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        theoryData.like.toggle()
        let likeIcon = theoryData.like ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart-icon") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart-empty-icon")
        likeButton.setImage(likeIcon, for: .normal)
        saveSelection()
    }
    
    private func saveSelection() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        var selectedItems = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "selectedCell") ?? []
        
        if theoryData.like {
            selectedItems.append(theoryData.id)
        } else {
            selectedItems = selectedItems.filter{ $0 != theoryData.id }
        }
        print(selectedItems)
        defaults.setValue(selectedItems, forKey: "selectedCell")
    }
 }
```