# Static keyword in swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I want a functionality to implement that if a user click the tableview cell for the first time it should get a checkmark as accessory indicator and if he clicks twice then the checkmark should disappear i.e. for every odd number of click the checkmark should be there and for every even number of click the checkmark should disappear.

I know what should be done i.e. in did select delegate method of tableview there should be a static variable whose count will increase with everytime the method gets called and then conditionally we can put the checkmark as accessory indicator.

I am recently learning swift 3 and not able to use static keyword here.What is the best way to achieve this thing in swift 3 .Kindly give suggestions .

Comment: Make get set property to observe state of this object.

Comment: Since there are only two states you need a boolean property (`selected`), the number of clicks / even or odd doesn't matter. And basically rather than a static variable you need a data model to be able to handle all cells of the table view individually.

Comment: Can u explain the same thing through code...I will be very thankful as I am new to this thing and need little direction to move forward.

Comment: There are many related questions and answers here on SO for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307168/save-retrieve-tableviewcell-checkmark-using-nsuserdefaults-in-swift/39307841#39307841 . In `didSelectRow...` just toggle the state of the  `selected` property

Comment: Why do you think you need a static variable for this kind of homework?

Comment: I had no idea about the selected property of cell before,now I understood that it can be achieved through selected property also...I wanted static property so that I can get the exact count of cell tapped.

Answer (score -1):

There are many way to do this.In didselect mehod of tablebview give a check image and in didDeSelect method give an uncheck image.Or you can add 1 in your array in didselect method,And replace that 1 with 0 in diddeselect method.Or in your cellForRow method you can check on that basis.