# Preserve Button State When Switching Between View Controllers

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

I currently have a navigation controller with 2 view controllers. After clicking Button A on VC 1, it brings me to VC 2. VC 2 has a checklist. When selecting the desired items from the checklist, I am able to select and deselect the checklist buttons. Then I click the back button on VC2 to return to VC 1. When I want to edit the checklist in VC 2, I click Button A to go back to VC 2 but the checklist has reset back to its default state and none of my selections are saved.

I have looked into Model View Controllers, Unwind Segues, UserData, Popping View Controllers but I am still very confused as to what to pick and stick to, for this to work.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UserDefaults` for saving information. But remember, use it if the data you are saving are reasonably small (sounds like an array of strings/booleans).

For learning UserDefaluts go to this [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-userdefaults).

Here are two links [1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128167) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307168/save-retrieve-tableviewcell-checkmark-using-nsuserdefaults-in-swift) can help you with your problem.
Let me know if it is helpful.